# Find $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!(n^4+n^2+1)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, polynomials, factorial

**Problem_**

> Find the value of
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!(n^4+n^2+1)}$$

It was quite difficult for me to deal with the given series because of the factorial in the denominator. For the series of factorial, I know the fact that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{x^n\over n!}=e^x$$
Can we change the form of this series similar to(or exactly as same as) the given series?

When I segregate the series into partial sums, 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!(n^4+n^2+1)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{1\over n!}{1\over2n}\left({1\over n^2-n+1}-{1\over n^2+n+1}\right)\\={1\over2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{1\over (n+1)!-n!}\left({1\over n^2-n+1}-{1\over n^2+n+1}\right)$$

However, the terms are not eliminated by other terms, so I think it is not a right way. Besides, Riemann Sum did not give any any clues to solve. Is there other way to have the value of the series? If so, please teach me! Thanks.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3339016/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2029003/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/794272/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn!(n%5E4%2Bn%5E2%2B1)%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Thanks, sir! It really helped.